# DNA fingerprinting

Tags: dna, human-genetics, pcr, restriction-enzymes

I would like to make my own DNA fingerprint - just for fun to have my "autoportrait":).

I was looking around a bit and all the commercial kits you can have are very expensive. Can you suggest me a cheaper way to do it - which DNA extraction protocol do you recommend?

I have access to restriction enzymes, we have several different pcr polymerases (Herculase, pfu). Can this be used to make PCR with human DNA?
I found this list with primers for different STR loci. http://www.cybertory.org/resources/CODIS/#Primers

If I understand it correctly I have to extract DNA, digest it with restriction enzyme and make a pcr with each of primer pair and than load it to a gel and make a picture. Am I getting it right?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: You might be interested by [this Ted talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/ellen_jorgensen_biohacking_you_can_do_it_too.html)

Comment: What about SNPs instead of fingerprinting or STRs? There are some companies which perform genotyping at hundreds of thousands of loci for acceptable money.

Comment: The idea is that I do it by my self not just send DNA to some company.